# Can this be formulated as a regression problem?

Tags: regression, generalized-linear-model, forecasting, linear-model

If I have a set of product title and their monthly sales data, such as:

```
$369 Harry Potter Books Set #1-7 in Collectible Trunk-Like Toy Chest Box, Decorative Stickers Included by Harry Potte

$102 Harry Potter and the Cursed Child, Parts 1 & 2, Special Rehearsal Edition Script
```

...

Now given a new product title, I want to predict the monthly sales dollar of this new title. Is there any regression model that will be appropriate for this prediction?

Comment: In principle, yes, this is regression - you are trying to predict a continuous output value. There are many, many, many ways to approach this problem.

Comment: @NuclearWang, then how to generate or represent features from the string title?

Answer (score 2):

That is fairly complicated because you are attempting to use a combination of string inputs to determine the worth. But it's not just that, you are interpreting the portion of value in relation to another title.

In the case above, you would need a system to determine that the second book is one within a series described by the first title. That sort of thing requires complex processing to determine. No clue what that looks like from a programmatic standpoint.

But your broad process is:

- Determine what the title is
- Find relevant titles
- Extract relevant information about those titles
- Predict price of the original title

The first two steps involve natural language processing (NLP) which then allows you to select the set of features and relevant information to run some predictive analysis against.

It is outside of the scope of regression in my opinion and is closer to ML techniques like an neural network of some sort. Seems like a fairly large undertaking

Comment: Regarding this, "to determine that the second book is one within a collection described by the first title", please elaborate on this a little bit more.

Comment: My mistake, I'm unfamiliar with those books, I thought the "Cursed Child" was one of the original 7 books. I now see it's seperate, but the point still stands. This system would need to recongize through features of the title (and author, etc) that they share a common source of valuation.

Comment: Probably an impossible mission :)

Comment: Consider 2 (fake) books: "The Lost Woods" and "Lost in the Woods" - one is a fantasy story about a magical "Lost Woods" and the other is a horror story about being lost in the woods. Basing their similarity on title alone might suggest they are extremely similar. You would need a system that can interpret all of the relevant information and then use all of that to predict a price.

Comment: "all of the relevant information", you mean information in addition to title only?